# What is the proper way to create an Admin UI based on a model in Sails?

Tags: forms, user-interface, sails.js, ejs

In Sails, I want to create kind of an Admin Area, like an interface to populate the database based on the models I created.

As far as I know, there is only a couple CLI Tools that can be used to create Actions and Models and so on, but nothing to have a proper EJS template defined on the models.

I found a couple npm modules that were going in this direction but they seem old.

Comment: As far as I know, this does not exist in any ready-to-use format. Sails has all the tools (quick blueprint API, policies for admin-only, ...) but I think you would just have to build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to build it myself, but I face a new problem related here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60284005/ajax-form-action-not-triggered-in-sails-js

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing quite like that. Yet, you can archive similar things with other tools provided by sails.

1. If you want to populate the database for development or testing, blueprint.js is a good option.
2. If you want to populate the database for production, you can create a new controller like:

   //AdminController.js

   ```
   module.exports = {

       createNewRace: function(name) {

           Races.create({...});

       },

       addDog: function(name, owner, race) {

           Races.update({...});
           Dogs.create({...});

       },

       ... and so 

   };
   ```

Then...

```
sudo sails console
var adminC = require('./AdminController');
adminC.createNewRace('Argentine Dogo');
```

This had been really useful for me, I've been trying to learn how to automate it, but I didn't find anything yet.

3. If you really need an UI because not only you will be populating the db

Create it your self, otherwise, some database servers have UI plugins available for doing those things. Like phpmyadmin for mysql and php. I think redis has one of those too. But if other admins are also user, it is not a good idea to give them access to your database without a secure api in the middle.