# Ajax form action not triggered in Sails.js

Tags: ajax, forms, sails.js

I created an action in Sails.js to create an entry in a database (add a customer). Then I created a form in EJS. (My code is based on the signup route / form)

I have my `Customer.js` models

I have my `view-create-customer.js`

I have my `create-customer.page.js`

I have my controller "action" `create-customer.js`

cloud.setup.js has `"createCustomer":{"verb":"POST","url":"/api/v1/entrance/create-customer","args":["customerName","status"]}`

In routes.js I have :

```
'POST /api/v1/entrance/create-customer': { action: 'entrance/create-customer' },
```

The ajax-form in my EJS Form I have :

```
<ajax-form action="createCustomer" :syncing.sync="syncing" :cloud-error.sync="cloudError" @submitted="submittedForm()" :handle-parsing="handleParsingForm">
```

The form displays just fine, but nothing happens when I click submit. No error, no ajax triggered.

I tried to POST to the API url with POSTMAN and my customer was created as expected.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running `sails run rebuild-cloud-sdk` after modifying your endpoint? Postman should work as it doesn't use the SailsJs 'Cloud' used in the action of the ajax-form component.

Also, can you share the response from POSTMAN ?